# How to compare today date is greater than or equals to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

compare 2 dates
if (from_date >= today && totime < = today)
 i tried with this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
NSString * TodayDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

if ([displayList.fromTime compare:TodayDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");

} else if ([displayList.toTime compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can comparing NSString, which is wrong. You need to compare two NSDate objects.**

Here is update code:

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    // You are doing wrong compareing at here. You need to compare Date nor sting.
//    NSString * TodayDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *TodayDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *compareData = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-07-09 11:12:11"];

    if ([compareData compare:TodayDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");

    } else if ([compareData compare:TodayDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"dates are the same");

    }
```

Comment: is it possible to do greater than or equall

Comment: It will take time and date both, so if date is same and time is ahead then it will return NSOrderedDescending. So it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying what class of object fromDate is, but since you're comparing it to TodayDate, which is a string, I'm assuming all of your dates are strings when you compare them? If so, that's a bad choice. Date comparison and string comparison are not the same and will yield different results.

Instead of turning today's date into a string, you should turn fromDate into an NSDate, and then compare those.

If, OTOH, fromDate is not a string, then that's your error. Just because two objects result in the same text being NSLogged doesn't mean they're the same type and can be compared, so make sure they're all the same type (NSDate) and then compare those.